# Coefficients of members in a base-point free linear system

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, birational-geometry

Let $\mathbb{K}\in \{\mathbb{Z},\mathbb{Q},\mathbb{R}\}$ and let $D$ be a base-point free(or ample if it is necessary) $\mathbb{K}$-divisor on a normal projective variety.

I have two questions:

1. When $\mathbb{K}=\mathbb{Q}$ or $\mathbb{R}$, can we always take $D^\prime\in |D|_{\mathbb{K}}$ such that $D^\prime$ has arbitary small coefficients?
2. When $\mathbb{K}=\mathbb{Z}$ or $\mathbb{Q}$, is there an $E\in |D|_{\mathbb{K}}$ such that $E$ is a prime divisor?

Comment: Welcome new contributor.  Yes and yes (assuming the dimension of your variety is at least 2).  For the second question, use Bertini’s smoothness theorem and the connectedness theorem of Enrique’s-Severi-Zariski.  For the first question, use openness of the ample locus to show that if you perturb by a positive real linear combination of ample $\mathbb{Z}$-divisors, you can get an ample $\mathbb{Q}$-divisor.  Now apply the first question to these ample $\mathbb{Q}$-divisors.

Comment: @JasonStarr Thanks! I think the problem is solved.